# Can we use bluetooth headset for listening music or something (not call) while using mic to record audio at the same time without mixing both sounds?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, wireless-headset

I am confused over this issue. I want to know the real and deeply explained meaning of the term "headphone with inbuilt mic" and the one without it. I understand that it means that we can listen the call and reply (using mic) without getting close to  phone/computer's internal mic.

The first text given below says that applies to the case also when we are listening music (not necessarily call) and record the audio using the mic at same time without mixing both sounds- the music and recording voice. But I can't do that using my phone- I mean I have to pause music when I need to record. Thus, I can't understand that text.

> If you’re just using a Bluetooth headset to take a phone call, that might be fine. If you want to speak into your headset’s mic while listening to music, playing a game, or watching a video on your PC, you’ll be frustrated.

This originated from here:- https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/

Moreover, I also can't understand the bold lines in the below given text. So, please explain them too. It's source is:- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problem-with-using-headsets-handsfree-and-stereo/91eefa56-f6bb-45b7-90d8-be6ca89d8674

> Basically, the headphones seem to be split into two devices, one with great stereo sound and one which is the headset that contains the microphone (see images). Now, the problem is that can't use them at the same time: **As soon as I use an application that requires the microphone (which belongs to the headset), the sound output seems to be sent to that device instead of the stereo device.** This results in some really poor quality sound which is barely interpretable.

The above given texts are threads about bluetooth headsets' problems with PC. They describe how they work smoothly with Android and Mac but have some issues with Windows. However, along with that they also raise some points which I can't comprehend. I am relating with them because I bought bluetooth headset recently and with because of some knowledge void, I can't get some stuff and leverage them to full use.

Thus, please clear my doubts about bluetooth headsets once and for all. 
Thankew in advance!

Comment: For the bold part in your second quote you need to reread the earlier part of your quote: "headphones seem to be split into two devices" they are literally a "high quality audio output" device and a "low quality headset" device wrapped together. Only one can be used at a time.

Comment: @Mokubai but the person in the same text also says that he can use both at same time in mobile, but I can't. Similarly, other text person says that you can use both generally in bluetooth headsets, but- again - I am not able to do so. I have to pause music to record audio.

Comment: Yes, they are both **available** at the same time, not that they can both be **used** at the same time. If one is in use then it blocks the use of the other, that is exactly what it means and is saying.